# NginX as a Reverse Proxy Binding Issues

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I have a fresh Ubuntu 11 install on MediaTemple and setting up NginX as a reverse proxy. So static items are handled by NginX and the rest are handled by apache per these instructions:

http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(ve):Using_Nginx_as_a_Reverse_Web_Proxy

Everything went fine except when I did the last step of restarting apache and then restarting NginX. Apache restarted fine, but when I restarted NginX it gave an error about binding. I restarted the server, and then attempted to restart apache followed by NginX again. This time apache reports an error but NginX restarts fine.

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                     
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The latest errors in Apache log appear to be:

```
[Mon Nov 14 06:47:13 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Nov 14 06:47:14 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 14 06:47:31 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Per the instructions I have the server external IP in NginX and the localhost ip in the apache locations.

I then stopped NginX restarted Apache (worked fine again) and then when restarting NginX the errors for that came back:

```
Restarting nginx: [emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: still could not bind()
nginx.
```

Comment: Apache says something is listening to port 80 on IP 127.0.0.1. So something else is binding to port 80. What does your netstat say is listening?

Comment: Does this help? sudo lsof -i tcp:80
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 1459     root    3u  IPv4 1871631190      0t0  TCP localhost:www (LISTEN)
apache2 1462 www-data    3u  IPv4 1871631190      0t0  TCP localhost:www (LISTEN)
apache2 1463 www-data    3u  IPv4 1871631190      0t0  TCP localhost:www (LISTEN)
apache2 1464 www-data    3u  IPv4 1871631190      0t0  TCP localhost:www (LISTEN)
apache2 1466 www-data    3u  IPv4 1871631190      0t0  TCP localhost:www (LISTEN)
apache2 1467 www-data    3u  IPv4 1871631190      0t0  TCP localhost:www (LISTEN)

Comment: Per the link above NginX listens to my server ip on port 80 and apache listens to the local host on port 80.

Comment: The problem seems that both are listening on the same ip and port. I'd start by checking your /etc/nginx.conf (not mentioned in the guide you linked) for a listen directive in the default server. Then grep all the Apache configuration files for Listen and NameVirtualHost directives. You can start one and use netstat to check which IPs it is listening on to determine which server is the problem. Additionally, there is no reason to have Apache listening on port 80 - you could just as easily make it 81 or 8080, etc. (Although, the latter probably won't help in this case)

Comment: Cyberx86, There is no /etc/nginx.conf file that I can see. There is a /etc/nginx file. Is that the one you are referencing?

Comment: Edit your original post to append the `lsof` output to keep formatting.

Comment: Sorry - /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (although, you seem to have ruled that out). One more possibility comes to mind - I seem to recall (although, I can't find a source at the moment) that a server block without a listen directive will listen on all addresses on port 80. Check to see if nginx.conf (or any other file) has a server block without a listen directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear from the output you pasted that **nginx** is trying to bind on port 80 on all available IP addresses, not only on your public address.

You should carefully review all *listen* directives in the relevant **nginx** configuration files. You can do this by running `grep -r 'listen ' /etc/nginx/*`.

If you find output looking like **listen 80;** (with no IP address specified), you should replace it with **listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80**, where xx.xx.xx.xx is your public IP address.

Comment: @heavymark I don't see any output from the grep command in your comment. Is that intentional, or you simply forgot to paste it? :-)

Comment: Vladimir, thanks I've been trying to figure out the command to do just that. When I ran yours I get follow: http://pastie.org/2862176 At first, promising except the /default file it referenced per the original link, that is disabled, and it only uses my domain file. Also in that file, the 80 it referes to is commented out. And in the .conf file I finally found the two references about listen are also already commented out. Any more ideas?

Comment: I clicked enter to return to the next line but it submitted it, and then when I was typing the rest it said it was too late to edit the comment, so had to do a new one.

Comment: To note, I swapped out my server external ip with my.ip.address and my server domain with example.com for privacy.

Comment: To also add I searched apache as well and got the following which looks correct. I can add the local ip infront of the the ssl ports but the error seems to be about 80 so don't think that would fix the problem. grep -r 'Listen ' /etc/apache2/*
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:Listen 127.0.0.1:80
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443

Comment: You can run `netstat -ntlp` to make sure that Apache listens only on 127.0.0.1

Comment: On the other hand, your nginx configuration looks ok - there are no obvious virtual hosts listening on all interfaces. The problem is that the default policy is to listen on port 80 of all hosts, so I would suggest going through the configuration files, uncommenting the listen directives and adding 127.0.0.1 to them.

Comment: Actually I just tried adding the local ip infront of the 443's in the apache ports.conf file stop apache/nginx restarted them and now it appears to work. I wonder why it was complaining about 80 if it was really those that was the problem. Either way thanks, the grep commands really helped!

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue. (Ubuntu 10.04, 2 real IPs, one for Apache and one for nginx). Solution: every ***server {...}*** block in configuration files MUST have ***listen a.b.c.d:80***  directive. Otherwise nginx tries to use all available IPs.